# ASP.net Core Identity Complex Claims authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-authorization

I have to create an Authentication and Authorization environment for my ASP.NET CORE MVC Identity 2.1 application, with an API backend and IdentityServer4 as Authorization Server).

1. I have administrators
2. I have Projects.
3. Every user has to be in at least one project, except administrators.

I would give users a claim like "Role" and store something like "admin"/"user" in it.

Now it gets more complicated.

4. In every project, users have different roles, and sub roles and once again sub-roles of sub-roles (so, three tiers).

Currently, I solved the problem by using action filters and write them in front of each controller/method (where I see them fit). I also created tables for these three tiers, so that I can store which user is in which tier (and of course they have different access rights depending on that).

I also want the user to be able to have multiple projects open at the same time (in different browser tabs) so that they can switch between these as they desire. I currently solved this by sending the project id on every request in the URI.

I thought about using claims instead of my current action filter solution. I read a lot into that and watched the Microsoft Virtual Academy videos regarding this topic. But I fail to understand how I could use that in this scenario. Should I do claim requirements and copy the code from my action filters in them because claims identity can't handle my case by default?

Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: IdentityServer is for authentication, if you think it's for authorization, the design is already flawed.

Comment: Oh ok. So I currently use it only for authentication. But on login, the IdentityServer sends claims back to the client. Don't I also authorize the user with the claims that I receive from the identity server?

Comment: No, the application decides whether those claims are valid or not. IDS only provides them (if you allow the client to request them)

Comment: ok but so eg.: Identity server returns a claim "IsInProject=projectidXXX". Then the IDS provides this information, and the client decides to, base on the claim, allow the user to see that regarding this project. I'm aware that the client has to do this "check". But I don't know what would be a good structure for these claims. What if a user is in 100 projects? The JWT token would overflow. I read something about claims transformation, would that be an approach? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Because that's *not* what Identity Server is for. Again, IDS is for *authenticating* the user, and you have an *authorization* problem. IDS will give you the UserId, then, in the *application's* database, you check to what projects the provided UserId has access to. IDS doesn't care, at all, about those projects, only that specific application does.

Comment: ok, yes I get that. But what would you suggest in my case then? Any best practices or advice?

Comment: Given that there can be multiple roles, I'd just query what roles the user have upon loading a project or a list of projects

Comment: And you would store them as claims? I thought about that too, but I want the user to be able to open multiple projects at the same time - in different tabs

Comment: No, I wouldn't use claims for this. Claims are stored as cookies and they have a limit that applies to the whole browser, not just your application. Just check for permissions on the GET requests

Comment: Ah ok, so integrate the authentication into the API. Guess that makes sense since I don't have to incorporate any authentication for my mobile apps in the future. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So would it be okay to make a Requirement as a claim like "over21" in the examples? In my case, it would be something like "IsInProjects". As far as I understood Claims are used for authorization. So I would make this requirement validated in the API Controller for example.

Comment: No, leave the authentication in IDS. The point of IDS is to be able to know that the user is valid, doesn't matter how they got to the system. Claims can be used for authorization, but, as they are stored as cookies, you cannot give an user 500 role claims, at some point it will overflow and the value won't be valid anymore.

Comment: Yes, but if I add requirements handler I could check in them if the user is allowed to access? So I do the database query in the requirement